# I can't put double to Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce, double

I'm trying add decimal to numbers. Example: 1.45, 46.12 but I got an exception.

```
cn.Open();
string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO table(ID, Name, Price, HowMuch, Localization, Description) VALUES(@ID, @Name, @Price, @HowMuch, @Localization, @Description)");
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", textBox3.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HowMuch", textBox4.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Localization", textBox5.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", textBox6.Text);
```

Exception Message: "Invalid format of the input string.".
I'm using the System.Data.SqlServerCe

Comment: I think you should explicitly state your question so that people can better help you.

Comment: What exception??...Pls add more details

Answer (score 0):

At least you should use something like:

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", string.Format("{0:C}", textBox3.Text));
```

But without any control before it is a bit tricky to put directly user value as float. Then do something like:

```
try
{
  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", string.Format("{0:C}", textBox3.Text));
}
catch
{
  /// do something to alert user value is not corretly formatted
}
```

Comment: as ask Precious1tj, can you put more about your exception ?

Comment: This is all what I got. I can give you HResult, Source etc. if you want.

Comment: "Invalid format of the input string." is it. 1) Is it same exception with and without Parse() ? 2) do you get exception as well without non-string data base values ? (I mean only with ID and name).

Comment: 1) Yes
2) I can't do that because ID, Name, Price and HowMuch cannot be null. But when I put Price like 5 or 625 it works.

Comment: do you mean you put Price like 5 to textbox UI or to code ? If it is from textboxbox directly, can you check at you field format in DB ?

Comment: I put 5 to textbox and click button Add. Price in DB has got money format.

Comment: ok. Then you should workaround currency. Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479284/how-can-i-format-decimal-property-to-currency can help.

Comment: read that: "Do not use float." from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377098/best-currency-format-in-database instead of you should use decimal

Comment: I solved the problem! Just change money format to float in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
 SqlCeParameter parameter = new SqlCeParameter();
 parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
 parameter.Precision = 18;
 parameter.Scale = 0;
 parameter.Value = textBox3.Text;
cm.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: I'm not using the System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: I have a problem with your code. I do not know that structure to be able to change my code.

Comment: you should look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx to understand more around what Rahul said.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good idea to make sure that `textBox3.Text` is a valid decimal first...before you get to the insert routine.

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
```

Then you can add the parameter and value with:

```
using System.Data;
cm.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price;
```

> SqlDbType is part of System.Data.